# How do I get a colon in timezone of Joda DateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse my `DateTime` in a specific format to `String`.
Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withOffsetParsed();
DateTime formattedDate = fmt.parseDateTime(asString($client/date));
String result = formattedDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddZ");
```

Result:

> 2018-01-15+0100

What I want:

> 2018-01-15+01:00

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

> Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

so your code should be:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withOffsetParsed();
Date formattedDate = fmt.parseDateTime(asString($client/date));
String result = formattedDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddZZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ZZ` to output with a colon. So:

```
String result = formattedDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddZZ");
```

will output:

```
2018-01-15+01:00
```